# Access token issue when I get list of Albums for Facebook page using Javascript API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have initialized the FB Graph JS SDK like so, and just want to make a simple call to get the list of albums of my Facebook page:

```html
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '707131072721568',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Now when I call the `/albums` Graph API like so:

```
FB.api(
    "/piggyslasher/accounts",
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

It outputs the following error:

> An access token is required to request this resource.

I don't have any FB login system. I just want to get a list of albums from a regular public Facebook page.

Comment: You either have to make users login to your app, or make this API call server-side, so that you can use your app access token or a page access token (both of which you do not want to expose in client-side code.)

Answer (score 0):

All Graph API requests must use an access token. (even if the page is public)

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the access token without using a the PHP SDK, which requires the APP_SECRET. I can't put the APP_SECRET in the front-end javascript can I? A little code would help.

Comment: I have gotten the access token by going to this URL:
>https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=707131XXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials, but how do I incorporate this into later graph calls?

Comment: @Vik that's an app token. Take the time to read the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login. The JS SDK is not designed for what you want to do because it's client side login. If you want to use the PHP SDK you need to the hardcode the access token inside as well as ensure it has no expiry date. There are tons of post on Stack Overflow and Google that explain this. I have answered your original issue which was why you cannot get albums with JS SDK without logging in, the answer being, you need to login. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login